# doFilter throws null pointer exception

Tags: jsp

I've got simple filter `SimpleFilter`

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    Object o = null;
    o = session.getAttribute("enterAttr");

    if (o == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("/reservation/main.jsp");
        return;
    }

    boolean bool = (boolean) o;

    if (bool == true)
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
    else
        response.sendRedirect("/reservation/main.jsp");
}
```

I want to redirect user to `main.jsp` when session attribute `enterAttr` either false or null. 
But I always get NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.project.reservation.web.filter.SimpleFilter.doFilter(SimpleFilter.java:48)
```

What is wrong? I thought it will not proceed when object `o` is null. But it still throws this exception.

Comment: line 48 between `}` and `boolean bool = (boolean) o`. It seems error in `boolean bool = (boolean)o` but I add `if (o == null) ` in order not get to this line.